# VBScript RegEx pattern

Tags: vbscript

I need a pattern that does a very specific thing but after hours I can't achieve te expected result.

Sample string:

```
SELECT col1 FROM tbl1 WHERE col1 = (SELECT col2 FROM tbl2 WHERE col2=col2)
```

Expected result:

```
FROM tbl1 WHERE col1 = (SELECT col2 FROM tbl2 WHERE col2=col2)

    -> tbl1
    -> WHERE col1 = (SELECT col2 FROM tbl2 WHERE col2=col2)
```

Actual pattern:

```
FROM\s+([^\s,]+)[\s\S]+(WHERE[\s\S]+)
```

Actual result:

```
FROM tbl1 WHERE col1 = (SELECT col2 FROM tbl2 WHERE col2=col2)

    -> tbl2
    -> WHERE col2=col2)
```

I have tried using look ahead and other things but I can't make it group from the first 'WHERE'.

Note: Between 'tbl1' and 'WHERE' should match everything posible, not just a space.

Note2: It should group all after first 'WHERE' even if there is not a where later on.

Comment: You should publish a list of representative input/output pairs and at least a hint at your strategy to produce the outputs from the match objects.

Comment: Why the VB6 tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until more details are published, I claim that a non greedy pattern will solve the problem:

```
Option Explicit

Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
'r.Pattern = "FROM\s+([^\s,]+)[\s\S]+(WHERE[\s\S]+)"
r.Pattern = "FROM\s+([^\s,]+)[\s\S]+?(WHERE[\s\S]+)"
'Dim s : s = "SELECT col1 FROM tbl1 WHERE col1 = (SELECT col2 FROM tbl2 WHERE col2=col2)"
Dim s : s = "SELECT col1 FROM tbl1 WHERE col1 = (No  W h e r e  here)"
Dim m : Set m = r.Execute(s)
If 1 = m.Count Then
   Dim t : t = Join(Array("From", m(0).SubMatches(0), m(0).SubMatches(1), _
                          vbCrLf, vbCrLf, "->", m(0).SubMatches(0), vbCrLf, "->", m(0).SubMatches(1)))
   WScript.Echo s
   WScript.Echo t
Else
   WScript.Echo "no match"
End If
```

output:

```
cscript 44890052.vbs
SELECT col1 FROM tbl1 WHERE col1 = (No  W h e r e  here)
From tbl1 WHERE col1 = (No  W h e r e  here)

 -> tbl1
 -> WHERE col1 = (No  W h e r e  here)
```

Comment: It worked nicely, even with the second 'where'. Thx!